# $.post() function not working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have tried for days and nights to find a solution. Nothing.

I know how `$.post` works, but for some reason it just doesn't.

This what I'm trying to do.

1. Call the post function to a PHP page that queries the MySQL for a value (no input required).
2. Set a `<p>` as this value.

Any suggestions? Much appreciated.

```
function refresh()
{
$.post("check.php",change(data));
}

function change(text)
{
getElementbyId('money').innerHTML=text;
}
```

Comment: Show some code you have tried so far.

Comment: @DylanCross It's quite obvious from the question body.

Comment: I know what he's trying to do, but I would like to know what code he has tried.

Comment: How did you use `$.post`, what does not work exactly?

Comment: @user1292810: Your edit just now is not remotely sufficient. How are you calling `refresh`, for instance?

Comment: @user1292810 From your update we can see that most likely you don't know how `$.post` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a quickly done code up, but what about this?

```
function change(text)
{
document.getElementbyId('money').innerHTML=text;
}


$.post('check.php', change);
```

Answer (score 6):

Definitely not how post works...

```
$.post("check.php", change);


function change(text)
{
   document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: Or simple `$.post("check.php", change);`.

Comment: so i need to call it like that?

Comment: You also need to `document.getElementbyId`

Comment: @AlexWayne And fix syntax error as well: `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

Or even more simply...

```
$.post("check.php",change);
```

You don't want to call the change function when you're setting up your ajax call.  You want pass your callback function to `$.post()`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is calling getElementById without "document", you shoud use:

```
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=text;
```

or (if you are using jQuery)

```
$("#money").html(text_value);
```

Try this code:

```
function refresh()
{
   $.post('check.php', function(data) {
     $("#money").html(data);
   });
}

refresh();
```

Comment: Ok so on my php page I echoed the results from the mysql_query.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a handler function you need to omit the argument and only provide the handler function name, or wrap the handler functionwith argument  in an anonymous function

```
$.post("check.php",change);
```

or

```
$.post("check.php",function(data){
   change(data)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (test in http://jsfiddle.net/sRZ7z/1/ ):

```
    function refresh()
    {    
         $.ajax({
              //replace your url
              url: '/echo/html/',
              type: 'POST',
              // you can delete "data" parameter if not needed
              // is only for testing ajax on jsfiddle addording to the documentation
              // http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html
              data: {
                    html: "Test ajax"
              },
         }).done(function ( data ) {
              $("#money").html(data);
         });
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
         refresh();
    });
```